# can it be solved in linear time, did this in n^2 time

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, performance

the problem goes like this

suggest a data structure and write a program to count the number of employees referred by an employee(directly or indirectly) in linear time. for example

```
  A B C D E F G 
A 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 A referred 4 (A referred B, B referred C and D and D referred E)
B 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 B referred 3 
C 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
D 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 D referred 1
E 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
F 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 F referred 1
G 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

did this using a two dimensional array, can it be done in linear time?

Note that an employee can obviously not be recommended by someone he directly or indirectly recommended, so there will be no cycles in the graph.  A new employee can be recommended by only one employee. while each employee can recommend multiple employees.

Comment: I can only think of an O(n) algo, how did you do it in O(N^2)? Reading the file is O(M) where M is the number of characters, but I assume that reading not included.

Comment: The adjacency matrix has n² entries, and the program needs to read the whole matrix, so it will necessarily take at least n² time.

Comment: 0 and 1 indicate which employee refered whom e.g in the first row A reffered only B so there is 1 and the rest are 0

Comment: Why must it be a matrix?

Comment: Is the information you posted your answer (adjacency matrix) or part of the original question? I don't believe you have posted the entire question but maybe a small summary of it.

Comment: Can we clarify if N is the number of employees or amount of data?  I think N must be the amount of data...

Comment: It is only the representation of the problem not necessarily a matrix. can use any data structure.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: I can't figure out how to do [this one](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=528f3074ea131cb725efd81369660f74-542192d2d8aca3c820c7acc656fa0c68) in O(n)

Comment: Why not use an acyclic directed graph or whatever you call it.

Comment: @Saqib would you post the entire original question so we could better help you

Comment: @PaulRenton I don't think anything is missing from the question, the question as posted says "Suggest a data structure"

Comment: Only the upper half of the matrix is used. Is that just a coincident or an inherent property of your data structure?

Comment: Disjoint-set data structure is used for connectedness of a set. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure#Applications

Comment: Why is this tagged C++ and Java?  Pick a language.

Comment: Can it be so that A referred B and B referred A?

Comment: [run length encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding)?

Comment: If A referred B then A is already an employee, Employees can refer only new employees

Comment: @Saqib: While obvious in hindsight, that's not obvious in your question, and is _very_ related to the answer.

Comment: @Saqib: can a new employee be recommended by multiple existing employees?

Comment: @MooingDuck: No, a new employee can be recommended by only one employee. while each employee can recommend multiple employees.

Comment: You know how I know this isn't a real world problem?  Because I was recommended by an employee who left and then was hired back on my recommendation.  Circular references are possible in actual situations.  Just FYI.

Comment: For any one solution to the problem, are we supposed to count the number of employees referred by just one employee or the number of employees referred by each one (that is, all) of the employees?

Comment: linear time in the traversal of employees or referrals?

Answer (score 2):

My solution using C#, I'm pretty sure this is less than N^2 but I'll need to look at it a little longer.  Posting for critique while I do so.

```
public class Employee
{
    public List<Employee> Referred { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CountOfRefer { get; set; }
    public bool BeenCounted { get; set; }
    public Employee()
    {
        Referred = new List<Employee>();
    }
}

    public static void main()
    {
        Employee A = new Employee(){ Name="A" };
        Employee B = new Employee(){ Name="B" };
        Employee C = new Employee(){ Name="C" };
        Employee D = new Employee(){ Name="D" };
        Employee E = new Employee(){ Name="E" };
        Employee F = new Employee(){ Name="F" };
        Employee G = new Employee(){ Name="G" };

        A.Referred.Add(B);
        B.Referred.Add(C);
        B.Referred.Add(D);
        D.Referred.Add(E);
        F.Referred.Add(G);
        List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>()
        {
            A, B, C, D, E, F, G
        };

        foreach (var emp in employees)
        {
            if (!emp.BeenCounted) countRefers(emp);
        }
    }

    private static int countRefers(Employee emp)
    {
        if (!emp.BeenCounted && emp.Referred.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (var refs in emp.Referred)
            {
                emp.CountOfRefer += countRefers(refs);
            }
        }

        emp.BeenCounted = true;
        emp.CountOfRefer += emp.Referred.Count;
        return emp.CountOfRefer;
    }
```

Basically when counting an employee it recurses down the tree until it finds a person who has no refers (which should be guaranteed to be there, since people can't refer eachother (I guess unless there is only 1 person, ignoring that case for now)).  Then if it has to calculate anybody through the recursion it sets a flag so it doesn't need to calculate it again.

Comment: `foreach (var emp in employees) ... foreach (var refs in emp.Referred)`  why yes, that _is_ O(N^2)  (Optimized sure, so fast, but still O(N^2).)

Comment: Eh, yeah I guess you are right, seemed more clever as I was writing it.  The first foreach doesn't have to execute any code if it gets iterated in the second loop, and the second loop doesn't execute if they have no refers.  Whether I can prove that somehow isn't N^2 is unlikely though.

Comment: Hold up, I'm rethinking this, the outer loop is you calculating the results for each employee I think, rather than just the first employee, and the inner loop/recursion has an _upper bound_ of the number of employees (or does it?), so even though it _appears_ O(N^2), I'm no longer sure it is....

Comment: how is it O(N^2)? Each employee only has in it the employees it has referred. Say I have 5 employees, N^2 would mean that you would have to consider 25 items to move forward. This worst case scenario is 2N -1 aka n not n^2 where each employee refers the next employee. Am I wrong?

Comment: @VoronoiPotato: I think `countRefers` gets called _up to_ 25 times for five employees (in the worst case).  That'd be the easiest way to tell I think.

Comment: I'm ignoring the bugs in the code that only make the answer accurate for the first employee obviously

Comment: No wait, since the input cannot have loops, this does top out at `2N`(ish), so yeah, this is linear time.  +1

Comment: I counted it out, I got 11 times, I don't think it's n^2

Comment: Yeah the assumptions is that employees cannot refer eachother, and someone has to exist that didn't refer anyone.

Comment: @VoronoiPotato With OPs test data it gets called 6 times (I put a static counter and writeline in there)

Comment: yeah I was counting the inner and outer loops which sounds wrong.

Comment: @VoronoiPotato Ah I see, in that case I get 13.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia: I just got further validation that each employee also has only one "referrer", which definitely simplifies the problem.

Comment: @MooingDuck Do you still think there's a bug in the code?  Aside from infinitely recursing if there is a refer loop, it seems to work for any test input I give it.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia: I believe it only calculates the right answer for the first employee, maybe the second or third if you're lucky.  You never clear BeenCounted ... wait... each person only has one referrer... Nope!  Your code is fine!

Comment: I wrote two C++ versions of this code.  [O(1) average with simple initialization](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=746c58a61edba588580fc1b72f3e6a4c-cc73e281b3b6abc9bf6cf4f153b944a6) and [O(1) worst case with two-phase initialization](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=32372ef0f87d66e2005846decf442e55-cc73e281b3b6abc9bf6cf4f153b944a6) (excluding the fact I return sets of referrers rather than merely the count, since I didn't want my counting algorithm to modify the data)

Answer (score 0):

Graph method: first construct a directed graph (a tree in this case) where each node represents an employee and points to the node of the employee that referred them. This should take O(N^2) worst case ((N^2)/2 checks to be precise) where N is the number of employees. You should, as you're constructing this graph, keep track of the leaves of this tree (the employees that did not refer anyone) and then trim these nodes (assigning zero to their number of referrals) and adding 1 to the number of referrals of the employees that referred them. Then repeat with the new leaves, except add 2 to each of their referring nodes number of referrals. This whole trimming and counting process should take O(N) as well, and at the end all of the nodes contain the number of referrals each employee made.

This is assuming there are no cycles or weird two-employees-referring-the-same-employee situations in your graph (i.e. it is in fact a tree).

So, no, can't be done linearly if the input data to the problem is the binary vectors you have described. If we were given simply the names of the hired employees with each node, then O(N) would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a graph first.  This mustn't be included in the O(n) as it is clearly O(n^2)

It is not clear if you optimise the duplicate references (Imagine all the values are 1)

At this point you can start at one node and add all the referred nodes e.g. in a bit mask. Any values which were added you need to navigate recursively until you are adding no new nodes.

The number of nodes you visit is O(N) as each employee can refer one person.

Comment: All 1s is impossible, an employee can only be referred to by 1 person.

Comment: Why is building a graph O(N^2)?  If N is the amount of data, then it's trivial to assemble a adjacency matrix in O(n)

Comment: @MooingDuck It is not clear if N is the amount of data of the number of individuals.  If it is the later, the size of the file is O(N^2)

Answer (score 0):

***Java*** If cheating is allowed: an enum might represent the graph.
Write first A(B), B(C, D), ... and then reorder so there is no forward reference on which the compiler complains. (This is always possible for non-cyclic references. Even a compile-time check against cyclic references.)

```
public class Refers {
    enum RefEnum {
        C(),
        E(),
        G(),
        D(E),
        F(G),
        B(C, D),
        A(B);

        //private final RefEnum[] refs;
        public final int refCount;

        private RefEnum(final RefEnum... refs) {
            //this.refs = refs;
            int n = 0;
            for (RefEnum ref : refs) {
                 n += 1 + ref.refCount;
            }
            refCount = n;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (RefEnum ref : RefEnum.values()) {
            System.out.printf("%s has %d refers%n",
                    ref.toString(), ref.refCount);
        }
    }
}
```

The algorithm stays O(N²) however.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tree (more precisely a forest). Read the edges in O(n) time. Construct the tree in O(n.log(n)). Given a node, visit and count descendants in O(n).

Comment: N-trees often have O(n.log(n)) operations, but this isn't a N-tree.  I Can't figure out how you would construct the tree in O(n.log(n)), I can only figure out O(n) and O(n^2)...

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain adjacency list for all the employees (N space). Then for each employee, maintain a Bag like data structure for all the referred employees. Then to count the references for Employee A, you can run DFS (Depth First Search) starting from A which is linear time algorithm.

Java code is here -

http://yogeshsp.blogspot.com/2013/04/graph-api.html

http://yogeshsp.blogspot.com/2013/05/depth-first-search-dfs-graph-processing.html